# Cookie в k6 browser

Tags: javascript

Как установить куки для k6 browser? В документации описаны куки только для http объекта, не могу найти информацию, можно ли их вообще устанавливать для browser.

Comment: а что именно не устраивает, куки ставятся к запросу, указываются непосредственно в запрос. Что значит установить для браузера? Чтобы указаные куки шли во всех запросах?

Comment: Ну для запросов, с объекта http, их явно можно указать. Есть объект cookieJar или просто cookie,  а для new Page нет таких атрибутов, https://k6.io/docs/using-k6-browser/overview/

Comment: куки привязываются к домену, по сути new Page является пустой, домена нету, вот и нету смысла указывать куки там

Comment: Ну при page.goto(url) происходит запрос, вот для него мне необходимо установить куки

Comment: https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-experimental/browser/browsercontext/addcookies/ это поможет, если установить в контекст браузера под нужный урл то при page.goto возьмет их

Comment: Да, это то что я не нашел, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-experimental/browser/browsercontext/addcookies/ это поможет

Если установить в контекст браузера под нужный урл то при page.goto возьмет их